# How to set max-width for all human readable text (not for tables &ct)

Tags: html, css

In general, I try to avoid using any style sheets and the like.  But there is one reason to insist on a fixed layout.  And that is the maximal width of a text line to read. Lines that are longer than a certain amount of characters are unreadable to humans.

Still, the max-width in all browsers and W3C documents defaults to the actual width displayed. This is very annoying when explanatory text and very big tables are displayed in
the same browser window. You have put your browser full screen (f11 in many browsers), and now you can no longer read the explanatory text...

What is the minimal way to indicate that `<p>` and all other places where simple floating text appears are set to a maximal width? Currently I have `p { max-width: 70ex; }` but there are so many other places like `<li>`

Comment: I just realize that stackoverflow displays about 110 characters in a line and is still readable. But that seems to be the very upper limit..

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea.  You would be taking control away from the user in an area where the user is best placed to decide.  Some people might prefer to have longer lines of text?  If it is not a design element, I would leave it.  Plus, unless you configured a print stylesheet that overrode the `max-width`, you might be forcing people to print on more pages than desired.

Comment: We agree that enforcing this in general does not make sense. But look at the pages like [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/visuren.html#box-gen) and look at the page in fullscreen. It rarely makes sense to permit such formatting by default.

Comment: Your claim that >80 characters of text is 'unreadable' is highly questionable. I have no trouble with it and I haven't met anyone other than yourself who claims to have this limitation. 80 characters was an 70's era hardware limitation/convention, I've never heard it claimed it was a deliberate decision based on human perception.

Comment: @SpliFF: I removed the controversial number 80 from my question. The problem occurs if you have a very wide screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could do something like this :

```
a, address, blockquote, caption, cite, code, dd, del,
dfn, li, p, pre, q, td, textarea, th, tt { max-width: 70ex }
```

there isn't any div on purpose or it could mess your site. that's why i would probably do something like :

```
.humanText { max-width: 70ex }
```

and put that class in your html tag

Comment: Thank you! I believe there is also dt.The idea is to write html with minimal overhead. So an extra class doesn't do it.

Comment: Since my question was about the minimal solution, and nobody has offered a better one, you win!